# Why eloquent can not update row

Tags: php, eloquent

I'm trying update row in eloquent this is my model. [Model publicoObjetivo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w02Zp.png)

And this is my controller
[function like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ik14C.png)

The response return 1 => true but in the data base the row dont update 
what happend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning the function before commit, so the results are never written to DB.
You must first check if the result is ok, then commit, and after commit return the function. Something like this:

```
$respuesta = PublicoObjetivo::where('codigo', '=', '333')->update(['megusta'=>'1']);

if ($respuesta) {
    DB::commit();
    return $response->withStatus(200)
                    ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                    ->withJson($respuesta);
} else {
    DB::rollback();
    //return error
}
```